# Gluon fails to load native plugin when application is manually closed and restarted

Tags: android, gluon, background-service, gluon-mobile

Gluon fails to  load native plugin when application is manually closed and restarted

I am trying to use Gluon for an application. I need to run a service in the background that needs to stay alive forever as it keeps polling for changes on the server and need to notify users when things change.

Gluon samples directory does not have a single example that tells how to run a background service. https://gluonhq.com/developers/samples/

I have implemented the background service following answers posted on this thread (and few others on SO). 
[Creating an Android background service that continuously polls a REST API for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169469/creating-an-android-background-service-that-continuously-polls-a-rest-api-for-da)
It appears quite easy to setup and run a background service using pure Android.

I have followed the Gluon plugin example to implement my own Android service plugin.

I am able to start the service in background. However, if I manually close all apps and try to launch the app again, Gluon fails. The service does keep running on the background. But the app seems to get all messes up and cannot load the naive plugins properly.

1. Find the Android implementation of my service and throws this error when this method is called in the application init method:  `Services.get(MobilePlatformService.class).get()`

   ```
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329):    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:131)
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329):    at com.demo.apps.mobile.demo._init(demo.java:101) - CALLS Services.get(MobilePlatformService.class).get()
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329):    at com.demo.apps.mobile.demo.init(demo.java:53)
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
   06-24 10:28:23.314: W/System.err(12329):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$138(LauncherImpl.java:182)
   06-24 10:28:23.315: W/System.err(12329):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(Unknown Source:8)
   06-24 10:28:23.315: W/System.err(12329):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:13)
   06-24 10:28:23.315: W/System.err(12329):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
   ```
2. Upon init, the application needs the location of the application directory. But, since the service failed to find the Android implementation, I am unable to get the application directory

   ```
   06-24 10:28:23.526: W/System.err(12329): Loading FontFactory com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory
   06-24 10:28:23.526: W/System.err(12329): Subpixel: enabled
   06-24 10:28:23.535: W/System.err(12329): Freetype2 Loaded (version 2.5.0)
   06-24 10:28:23.535: W/System.err(12329): LCD support Enabled
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329): java.io.IOException: Private storage file not available
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.c(SourceFile:37)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a$$Lambda$2.get(Unknown Source:1)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:286)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.<clinit>(SourceFile:37)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.a(SourceFile:53)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:257)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:224)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(Unknown Source:4)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source:7)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(Unknown Source:4)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source:7)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(Unknown Source:2)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source:4)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:57)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(Unknown Source:4)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source:7)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
   06-24 10:28:23.859: E/a(12329):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
   ```

So, how to initiate the Gluon app properly so that it loads the Android(or ios) native service properly? It will be very useful for developers, if a working background services sample was posted on the Gluon samples page.

Comment: Without having a look at your implementation, it is impossible to say. If you want a Down plugin that implements a background service,  have a look at the Push notifications [service](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/8ba5d4408ff72795ce72f84a2081b53beffa13de/plugins/plugin-push-notifications/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidPushNotificationsService.java#lines-82). The Devoxx app uses this service. Check its Android [manifest](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/android/AndroidManifest.xml#L37).

Comment: There is nothing special in the implementation. It's exactly the same as the example link I have shared. And, the service is called same as in the example you gave. The problem happens when 1. the service is started via the intent. 2 application is force closed(at this point the service has died and restarted as the broadcast receiver has kicked in). 3 Application is launched again. Now the application fails to execute gluon command: Services.get(MobilePlatformService.class).get(). with error java.util.NoSuchElementException. Why is it failing the second time when custom down plugin is used?

Comment: Upon further debugging the problem certainly appears to be with Gluon. Basically, once a background service is restarted using a broadcast receiver from its onTaskRemoved method, the Gluon app cannot be run again. It fails to load any Down services. Services.get(... return empty for any service. Not sure where to file a bug report as the GluonHQ website only points to SO. Also, lack of such a critical feature required of modern mobile apps and the lack of technical support makes one very nervous about using this platform.

Comment: Gluon offers two basic ways of support: one here, one via support [at] gluonhq [dot] com. If you can provide here a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Aren't all the details provided above not enough to reproduce? Simple to reproduce, 1. Create a Down plugin that starts an Android service from an Intent. 2. Register a restart receiver. 3. "Close All" the app from the Android device. 4. App dies and Service starts. 5. Launch app again. Gluon is hosed. Cannot get any Service.get. At this time we are discussing moving to Android native development as we seem to be spending too much trying to get  basic things working. If we decide to give Gluon another shot, we will try to get you a MVCE. FYI, nobody responds to that email.Tried it before

Comment: Usually if you ask a question to get help, you are the one that have to provide the means for others to help you, and you can't expect others to do the work for you. If you post a good question, you have more chances to get a good answer. If it is so simple to reproduce, please post it here so we can see what you are trying to do. There are many details that you may have missed, like `singleTop`, or a missing line at the manifest... About support, can you point me to an email you have sent? Support emails are regularly attended (not immediately though).

Comment: There are custom libraries that are integrated into the App so it is not easy to simply post the entire project. There is big effort to strip it down to create a MVCE. As I said, will create MVCE if we decide to continue with Gluon. I do not expect others to do the work at all. However, if someone has already provided sufficient details and asking them to keep doing work to prove that there is a problem does not move things along. It's Gluon developers choice to investigate or ignore this issue. Other's may encounter this and may not even bother posting but just move on other env.

Comment: I understand that you won't post the whole project for a number of reasons, I'm not asking for it, I just need a MVCE to get started. You keep saying there is a problem out there... go and solve it! But that's not how this works. Time is valuable for everybody. You are free to use an OSS library like Charm Down. If you find an issue there, you can [report it](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/issues?status=new&status=open) if you want, but you will have to explain how to reproduce it in any case.

Comment: I have already explained how to reproduce it. Will get you MVCE if we move ahead with Gluon.Thanks for you help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Update. I have given up trying to get background services to work with Gluon. I spent a lot of time trying to use push notifications as alternative but Gluon does not work with Firebase. At this time I have concluded that Gluon is not the right platform for our needs and will not be able to provide the MVCE. We have switched to native Android and Multi-OS-Engine. We were able to get background services and push notification working for Android and iOS fairly easily and quickly with MOE. Though very promising and a superb alternative for building basic apps, Gluon has a very long way to go.